# Use only one of the characters in regular expression javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I guess that should be smth very easy, but I'm stuck with that for at least 2 hours and I think it's better to ask the question here.

So, I've got a reg expression `/&t=(\d*)$/g` and it works fine while it is not `?t` instead of `&t` in url. I've tried different combinations like `/\?|&t=(\d*)$/g` ; `/\?t=(\d*)$|/&t=(\d*)$/g` ; `/(&|\?)t=(\d*)$/g` and various others. But haven't got the expected result which is `/\?t=(\d*)$/g` or `/&t=(\d*)$/g` url part (whatever is placed to input).

Thx for response. I think need to put some details here. I'm actually working on this peace of code

```
var formValue = $.trim($("#v").val());
var formValueTime = /&t=(\d*)$/g.exec(formValue);
if (formValueTime && formValueTime.length > 1) {
    formValueTime = parseInt(formValueTime[1], 10);
    formValue = formValue.replace(/&t=\d*$/g, "");
}
```

and I want to get the `t` value whether reference passed with `&t` or `?t` in references like `youtu.be/hTWKbfoikeg?t=82` or similar one `youtu.be/hTWKbfoikeg&t=82`

Comment: Chuck in a the actual URL and expected output as examples and somebody will be able to figure it out fast.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: Use `s.match(/[?&]t=(\d+)/)[1]`

Comment: This one doesn't solve the problem. I've added some details to the topic. Anyway, thank you for response.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/yq09f4zL/1/ - does it solve the issue?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hey man. Thank you a lot. I've used your variant with exec like `/[?&]t=(\d*)$/g.exec(formValue);` and that worked just as good as it could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace, you may use

```js
var formValue = "some?some=more&t=1234"; // $.trim($("#v").val());
var formValueTime;
formValue = formValue.replace(/[&?]t=(\d*)$/g, function($0,$1) {
    formValueTime = parseInt($1,10);
    return ''; 
 });
 console.log(formValueTime,  formValue);
```

To grab the value, you may use

```
/[?&]t=(\d*)$/g.exec(formValue);
```

**Pattern details**

- `[?&]` - a character class matching `?` or `&`
- `t=`  - `t=` substring
- `(\d*)` - Group 1 matching zero or more digits
- `$` -  end of string

Answer (score 0):

```
/\?t=(\d*)|\&t=(\d*)$/g
```

you inverted the escape character for the second RegEx.

http://regexr.com/3gcnu

Comment: Thank you for response. This peace of code of yours works fine on `?` reference type and just ignored on `&` types. I've put some details in the topic.

Comment: @IgorChernega I don't understand what you mean? It works for both ?t=123456 and &t=123456

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank you all guys for trying to help. Special thanks to @Wiktor Stribiżew who gave the closest answer.

Now the piece of code I needed looks exactly like this: 
`/[?&]t=(\d*)$/g.exec(formValue);`

So that's the `[?&]` part that solved the problem. 
I use array later, so `/\?t=(\d*)|\&t=(\d*)$/g` doesn't help because I get an array like `[t&=50,,50]` when reference is `&` type and the correct answer `[t?=50,50]` when reference is `?` type just because of the order of statements in RegExp.

Now, if you're looking for a piece of RegExp that picks either character in one place while the rest of RegExp remains the same you may use smth like this `[?&]` for the example where wanted characters are `?` and `&`.